# IE11 JS Error const name => function

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue on IE11, this line of jquery is not recognize.....:

```
const applyHeights = (items, height) => {
```

Do you have any idea how to make it work ? It will be awesome ! it is all working fine on other browser such as chrome, safari, firefox, etc !

Thanks !

-- EDIT --

As the below:

```
let maxHeight = Math.max(...heights);
```

--ALL CODE --

```
setTimeout(function (){
setTimeout(function()  {
const applyHeights = function(items, height)  {
        const applyHeights = function(items, height) {
const applyHeights = function(items, height) {
        items.forEach(function(item) {
    let back = item.querySelector('.back'),
        front = item.querySelector('.front');

    back.style.height = height;
    front.style.height = height;
    item.style.height = height;
});
}

const getHeights =function (items, className) {
return Array.from(items).map(function(item) {
    return item.querySelector('.${className}').offsetHeight;
});
}

const initFlip = function(id) {
let element = document.getElementById(id);

if(!element) return;

initHeights(element);

window.onresize = function(event) {
    resetHeights(element);
    initHeights(element);        
}
}

const initHeights = function(element) {
let items = element.querySelectorAll('article'),
    backHeights = getHeights(items, 'back'),
    frontHeights = getHeights(items, 'front');

let heights = backHeights.concat(frontHeights);

var maxHeight = Math.max(...heights);

applyHeights(items, '${maxHeight}px');
}

 const resetHeights = function(element) {
let items = element.querySelectorAll('article');

applyHeights(items, 'auto');
 }
```

Comment: That's _Javascript_, not jQuery.

Comment: IE11 does not support ES6.  Use a transpiler.

Comment: SLaks, thanks, what does that mean ?

Comment: It means IE doesn't support the `=>` construct. You'll need an additional layer which proxies that, or you can convert the code to traditional function references, eg. `const applyHeights = function(items, height) {`

Comment: thanks a lot Rory ! it does the job, I've an edit an other line which seems to have the same problem, do you have an idea how to fix that one by an chance ? thx a lot !

Comment: For your second issue, have you tried changing `let` with `var`?

Comment: yes but no change :( still saying an error is on this line . . .  I m copying the all code in case it helps . . . thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The `(value)=>{}` syntax is called 'arrow function'. It is a feature of ecmascript2015 (ES6) , a script language specification. 
Internet explorer 11 does not support natively in ES6 .
In order to run ES6 on IE11 you will need a compiler that can compile es6 to es5 (that IE11 understand) the most common compiler for this  is babeljs. 
It has nothing to do with jquery.